# Is there any Java tool to communicate with an external CLI?

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I need a way to communicate with an external tool which has a Command Line Interface from my Java application. Is there any handy tool/lib to make it less painful? Believe me, I've googled enough. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417495/java-cli-ui-design-frameworks-or-libraries. Internet search for "Java shell" will yield a couple of possibilities. Pure CLI for embedding might be extracted from those projects too.

Comment: @JoopEggen I don't think that's what the OP wants, he needs to communicate with an external CLI tool, not to implement a CLI

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343066/reading-streams-from-java-runtime-exec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using the process handler (more specifically, the com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler) from Intellij IDEA platform API + writing my own small command-based framework where each command knowns how to execute itself (write) and parse the response from a process (read).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) for executing external commands of the operating system. Be aware, though, of the gotchas of using it - make sure to read this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) first.

If that's too simplistic for your needs, take a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). It's available since Java 1.5, from the [release notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/enhancements.html):

> The new ProcessBuilder class provides a more convenient way to invoke subprocesses than does Runtime.exec. In particular, ProcessBuilder makes it easy to start a subprocess with a modified process environment (that is, one based on the parent's process environment, but with a few changes).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm way past `Runtime.exec()`

Comment: @AlexanderEliseyev I updated my answer with another, better alternative

Comment: I need a way to **communicate** with a process, not to start it. I need a tool to ease the handling of the requests/responses while talking to the external CLI.